# Woocommerce product-category overriding

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a problem overriding standat Woocommerce template. I have a product category named "Parfyumeriya" on my website, so the link http://localhost/mywebsite/product-category/parfyumeriya/ shows the list of product in this category but it uses standart template. I want to use my own template, but I don't know which files of plugin's template should I edit. I tried content-product_cat.php, taxonomy-product_cat.php, archive-product.php, but nothing is working. Any ideas?

Comment: I think that if you have a file called `taxonomy-parfyumeria.php` that should load automatically when on that category archive if `parfyymeria` is the taxonomy terms' slug.

Answer (score 3):

If the template you want to replace or override belongs to woocommerce you will find it in the *wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates*.

To override it you have to create a folder in your child-theme also named *woocommerce* and copy the file (whole path inside templates) there where you can edit it and make changes to it.

For example:

*plugins/woocommerce/templates/taxonomy-product_cat.php* will be copied as *themes/your_child_theme/woocommerce/taxonomy-product_cat.php*

Regarding having a specific template for a product category the comment in the selected answer of this question says how to name the file:

`taxonomy-product_cat-{slug}.php`

[Woocommerce - Specific template for product category?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/95386/woocommerce-specific-template-for-product-category)

[Here there is a link to woocommerce docs](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/)