# How can I add and display a sidebar on Woo-commerce Shop page for a custom Wordpress Theme?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, woocommerce-theming

I feel like this should not be very difficult to do however I am having great difficulty figuring it out, thanks in advance for your help on this matter.

I am creating a Woo-commerce Store for my website and am using a custom Wordpress Theme I am building myself. I have installed Woo-commerce and set up the default pages including the Shop Page. I would like to add a sidebar to my Shop page (i.e where I display all products) and have this same sidebar appearing on all category and other sub pages from the shop page to assist in navigating my shop. In the sidebar I will add product filtering (to add some context) and I understand how to achieve this by adding widgets.

My issue however is I am unsure how to add and display a sidebar on the Shop and sub category pages. I do not want to have to overwrite the default php to achieve this (if possible) and would like to complete this as simply as possible however I have built a custom single-product.php page if this make a difference to my issue.

I have attached an image of what I am trying to achieve and what my current shop page looks like.

[image: Current Shop Page]

[image: What I am trying to achieve]

Comment: Could you please check the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47138788/woocommerce-product-category-overriding

Comment: I would like to achieve this (if possible) by adding a sidebar to my pages and not having to create a custom template for displaying products.

Comment: You can use the woocommerce hook `woocommerce_sidebar`

Comment: Where do I add this? Is this a shortcode that you add to a Shop page? Will this then be displayed on category pages as well as on the shop page displaying all products? Thanks for your help.